# google safe browsing api url encoding (canonicalization)

Tags: google-api, url-encoding, canonicalization, malware-detection

In my application I am checking user-entered urls for malware by sending them to google.

To test getting a "malware found" reaction I used the url http://malware.testing.google.test/testing/malware

To my surprise this url was not marked as malware

In fiddling about I found out that when I enter a trailing slash, it does get picked up as malware.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v3#Canonicalization) it says the url's need to be canonicalized.

Do any of you know of an implementation of this requirement? (preferably in c#)

Comment: Just want to know if you found a C# implementation?  The Java implementation in my answer needed a little work but it now passes the Google test suit.

Comment: I have switched project so my quest to fix this issue has been put on hold for now. I will return to this problem eventually (or my collegue) so if you have a working C# solution I am interested! Thx for your answer, once I have time to look into this I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the link [ForguesR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980659/forguesr) provided I have created this C# implementation.

It passes 26 out of the 33 tests from the google test suite found at: https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v3#Canonicalization

It has been deemed good enough for production since it doesnt catch the more obsure webpages.

Code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xO9sWl

Answer (score 3):

I am working on the same problem right now and the only thing I have found is a Java implementation in the [jGoogleSafeBrowsing](https://github.com/daveshanley/jgooglesafebrowsing) library.  Unfortunately, it is stuck to v2 of the API.

Anyhow, you can have a look at the canonicalization code [here](https://github.com/daveshanley/jgooglesafebrowsing/blob/master/v2/src/main/java/com/buildabrand/gsb/util/URLUtils.java).  Be aware that :

- this code is released as open-source under the Creative Commons NC-SA license;
- this code may not pass the [Google canonicalization test suit](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v3#Canonicalization).

Comment: Update: there is [Gsb4j](https://github.com/bazi/gsb4j) library which is a Java client implementation of Google Safe Browsing **API v4**. It has a canonicalization code with a [test class](https://github.com/bazi/gsb4j/blob/gsb4j-1.0.3/core/src/test/java/kg/net/bazi/gsb4j/url/CanonicalizationTest.java) that passes all test cases provided in docs.
Disclosure: I am the author of Gsb4j, open-sourced in 2018 (that's why a veery late comment here).